# How to remove data of a particular weekday in R?

Tags: r

I have data of 4680 rows.
following is the structure :

```
> str(mibid4)
'data.frame':   4680 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date      : Date, format: "1998-06-15" "1998-06-16" "1998-06-17" "1998-06-18" ...
 $ MIBID     : num  5.1 5.01 5 5.02 5.03 8.7 7.51 7.73 7.94 7.48 ...
 $ STD.DEV.  : num  0.0297 0.0234 0.0125 0.0254 0.0621 ...
 $ MIBOR     : num  5.25 5.14 5.09 5.18 5.18 8.99 7.91 8.04 8.21 7.71 ...
 $ STD.DEV..1: num  0.0312 0.0366 0.0214 0.0258 0.1411 ...
 $ day       : chr  "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" ...
```

I want to remove the data of 'Saturday'. The rows which have day=='Saturday'
How to remove such particular rows. I have created a 'day' column using using `weekdays`.

Comment: You should take a read of some introductory material on data management in R, like: http://www.statmethods.net/management/ It will cover a host of variations on stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mibid4[mibid4$day != 'Saturday', ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`subset` from base:

```
subset(mibid4, day != "Saturday")
```

`filter` from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
mibid4 %>% filter(day != "Saturday")
```